# Cake Bake - Table groups_users for model GroupsUser was not found in datasource

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

While I attempt to bake a model named DeploymentRequest, I get the following error:

`Table groups_users for model GroupsUser was not found in datasource`

If I look at my database structure, at no point a relation is made to that join table (nor does it need to exist). I do have the models Group and User acting as requesters for ACL purposes though.

Error:

```
Baking test fixture for DeploymentRequest...

Creating file C:\wamp\apscmdb\app\Test\Fixture\DeploymentRequestFixture.php
Wrote `C:\wamp\apscmdb\app\Test\Fixture\DeploymentRequestFixture.php`
Bake is detecting possible fixtures...
Error: Table groups_users for model GroupsUser was not found in datasource defau
lt.
#0 C:\wamp\cakephp-2.4.5\cakephp-2.4.5\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php(3498): Model->se
tSource('groups_users')
#1 C:\wamp\cakephp-2.4.5\cakephp-2.4.5\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php(1355): Model->ge
tDataSource()
#2 C:\wamp\cakephp-2.4.5\cakephp-2.4.5\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php(864): Model->sch
ema()
#3 C:\wamp\cakephp-2.4.5\cakephp-2.4.5\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php(892): Model->__i
sset('GroupsUser')
#4 C:\wamp\cakephp-2.4.5\cakephp-2.4.5\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\TestTask.ph
p(405): Model->__get('GroupsUser')
#5 C:\wamp\cakephp-2.4.5\cakephp-2.4.5\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\TestTask.ph
p(396): TestTask->_processModel(Object(Group))
#6 C:\wamp\cakephp-2.4.5\cakephp-2.4.5\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\TestTask.ph
p(396): TestTask->_processModel(Object(User))
#7 C:\wamp\cakephp-2.4.5\cakephp-2.4.5\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\TestTask.ph
p(376): TestTask->_processModel(Object(DeploymentRequest))
#8 C:\wamp\cakephp-2.4.5\cakephp-2.4.5\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\TestTask.ph
p(146): TestTask->generateFixtureList(Object(DeploymentRequest))
#9 C:\wamp\cakephp-2.4.5\cakephp-2.4.5\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTask.p
hp(854): TestTask->bake('Model', 'DeploymentReque...')
#10 C:\wamp\cakephp-2.4.5\cakephp-2.4.5\lib\Cake\Console\Command\Task\ModelTask.
php(109): ModelTask->bakeTest('DeploymentReque...')
#11 C:\wamp\cakephp-2.4.5\cakephp-2.4.5\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.php(431): ModelTa
sk->execute()
#12 C:\wamp\cakephp-2.4.5\cakephp-2.4.5\lib\Cake\Console\Shell.php(428): Shell->
runCommand('execute', Array)
#13 C:\wamp\cakephp-2.4.5\cakephp-2.4.5\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(207
): Shell->runCommand('model', Array)
#14 C:\wamp\cakephp-2.4.5\cakephp-2.4.5\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(66)
: ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#15 C:\wamp\cakephp-2.4.5\cakephp-2.4.5\app\Console\cake.php(36): ShellDispatche
r::run(Array)
#16 {main}
```

Database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE deployment_requests(
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  environment_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  revision INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  is_scheduled TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  requested_deploy_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  requested_deploy_time TIME DEFAULT NULL,
  additional_instructions TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  is_completed TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  created_by INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  modified_by INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE groups(
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name_eng VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  name_fra VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  description_eng TEXT NOT NULL,
  description_fra TEXT NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  created_by INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  modified_by INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 4
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 5461
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE users(
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  group_id INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  legal_given_names VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  legal_family_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 601943
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 3276
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Edit #1

User model:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * User Model
 *
 * @property Group $Group
 * @property AssetDeploymentUser $AssetDeploymentUser
 * @property AssetGroupDeploymentUser $AssetGroupDeploymentUser
 * @property DeploymentRequest $DeploymentRequest
 * @property DeploymentSupportRequest $DeploymentSupportRequest
 */
class User extends AppModel {
    public $displayField = 'name';
    public $virtualFields = array(
            'name' => 'CONCAT(User.legal_given_names, " ", User.legal_family_name)'
    );

    public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

    public function parentNode() {
        if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (isset($this->data['User']['group_id'])) {
            $groupId = $this->data['User']['group_id'];
        } else {
            $groupId = $this->field('group_id');
        }
        if (!$groupId) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return array('Group' => array('id' => $groupId));
        }
    }

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $validate = array(
        'legal_given_names' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'legal_family_name' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'email' => array(
                'rule' => array('email'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'username' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Group' => array(
            'className' => 'Group',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'AssetDeploymentUser' => array(
            'className' => 'AssetDeploymentUser',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
        'AssetGroupDeploymentUser' => array(
            'className' => 'AssetGroupDeploymentUser',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
        'DeploymentRequest' => array(
            'className' => 'DeploymentRequest',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
        'DeploymentSupportRequest' => array(
            'className' => 'DeploymentSupportRequest',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

Group model:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Group Model
 *
 * @property User $User
 * @property Asset $Asset
 */
class Group extends AppModel {
    public $displayField = 'name_eng';

    public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

    public function parentNode() {
        return null;
    }


    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed


/**
 * hasAndBelongsToMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'joinTable' => 'groups_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
        ),
        'Asset' => array(
            'className' => 'Asset',
            'joinTable' => 'assets_groups',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'asset_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
        )
    );

}
```

Comment: Do you have a GroupsUser model? If yes, then add the following to it:
`public $useTable = false;`

Comment: @jimmymadon That model doesn't exist in my code. I also do not have a table that would have the fields user_id and group_id creating such a relationship either.

Comment: Can you paste the User and Group model code (mainly the $actsAs and $hasMany, $belongsTo etc relationship properties)?

Comment: @jimmymadon see latest edit for code requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your database, I believe Group hasMany User and User belongsTo Group. Hence, remove the User array from the $hasAndBelongsToMany property and add the following in Group.php:

```
public $hasMany = = array(
    'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
     )
);
```

Comment: I came to the realization that some models simply had to be rebaked. When I rebaked the Group model, it baked like it should have, without the habtm property. I had assumed that those had been baked by a colleague or were up to date. I had to rebake 3 other models that gave me such issues. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I thought the Group / User models were baked with a different database surely than what you have given in your question. Was going to tell you to check your Assets and other model relationships or re-bake models again altogether.